# Solution of partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, warning-messages

How can I find the solution to

$\frac{1}{k^{2}}\partial_{y}^{4}\zeta(y,t)-\partial_{y}^{2}\zeta(y,t)+\frac{\varrho S}{f}\partial_{t}^{2}\zeta(y,t)=0$

with $\zeta(0,t)=\zeta(L,t)=0$ and $\partial_{y}^{2}\zeta(0,t)=\partial_{y}^{2}\zeta(L,t)=0$

using Mathematica ?

I tried:

```
DSolve[1/k^2*D[f[y, t], {y, 4}] - D[f[y, t], {y, 2}] - 
   p*S/f*D[f[y, t], {t, 2}] == 0, {D[f[0, t], {t, 2}] == 0, 
  D[f[L, t], {t, 2}] == 0, f[0, t] == 0, f[L, t] == 0}, {f[y, t], y, 
  t}]
```

It returns an error:

> DSolve::dsfun: (f^(0,2))[0,t]==0 cannot be used as a function.

I am not very familiar with `DSolve`, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot !

EDIT:
I separated the function f[y,t] and {y,t} as described by Michael E2:

```
DSolve[1/k^2*D[f[y, t], {y, 4}] - D[f[y, t], {y, 2}] - 
   p*S/f*D[f[y, t], {t, 2}] == 0, {D[f[0, t], {t, 2}] == 0, 
  D[f[L, t], {t, 2}] == 0, f[0, t] == 0, f[L, t] == 0}, 
 f[y, t], {y, t}]
```

but I get this error (also predicted by Michael E2):

> DSolve::dsvar: {y,t} cannot be used as a variable.

I don't see how to solve it.

EDIT 2:

Now, I don't get any error message anymore (replaced the "f" variable with a "g"):

```
DSolve[{1/k^2*D[f[y, t], {y, 4}] - D[f[y, t], {y, 2}] - 
    p*S/g*D[f[y, t], {t, 2}] == 0, D[f[0, t], {t, 2}] == 0, 
  D[f[L, t], {t, 2}] == 0, f[0, t] == 0, f[L, t] == 0}, 
 f[y, t], {y, t}]
```

But it does not solve the system.

Comment: Post your work you have tried so far

Comment: @JoseECalderon I added it.

Comment: Also intrested in that solution. Have a similar problem.

Comment: @totyped Let's hope someone knows.

Comment: `DSolve` has documentation, whose first synopsis states, "DSolve[eqn,u,x] solves a differential equation for the function u, with independent variable x." You do have three arguments, but the PDE system, pde & bcs, are split into two arguments and the function `f[y, t]` and independent variables `y`, `t`, are bound together into one argument. Fix these and you'll get another error that's easy to fix. The PDE tutorials found in [this guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveOverview.html) suggest `DSolve` has limited abilities with fourth-order PDEs.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you very much ... but I do not quit understand it yet. How do you want me to seperate y and t ?

Comment: I didn't suggest they should be separated.  I suggested that `f[y, t]` be separated from `{y, t}`.  Sorry if that was unclear, but I thought it was clear in the PDE examples in the docs. (Example: `DSolve[{BlackScholesPDE, bc}, v[t, s], {t, s}]`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 have a look at my edit... I still don't understand how to resolve the error.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you very much for your patience ! I fixed it, but now I get the error message: DSolve::dvnoarg: The function f appears with no arguments.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks. I saw, that f was both used as a variable and as a function. I swichted the variable to "g" but now, it does not resolve the system but puts no error either..

Comment: That's because `DSolve` doesn't know how to solve it, I guess, at least not in the present form. (See my first comment.) I don't have anything to suggest at this point, but now that the real problem is clear (assuming you will update the question with the new code), maybe someone else will have an idea. You could try a numerical approach (e.g. `ParametricNDSolve`), depending on what you wish to investigate.

Comment: @MichaelE2 okay. Thanky you for your help !

Comment: Where's the initial condition? Or you want a solution with parameters?

Comment: Also, you don't write 3rd and 4th b.c. correctly, it should be `D[f[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0 /. {{x -> 0}, {x -> L}}`